# Conflicto entre rutas de Laravel y Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Intento crear una SPA, pero decidi usar laravel para generar la autenticacion, por lo que estoy rutas de laravel para el login, y bienvenida. el problema es que dentro del sistema, quiero usar vue para los formularios y tablas, pero no se como hacer que laravel solo utilice dichas rutas, y las demas las utilice vue router?

Esta son mi rutas laravel

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('activity', 'ActivityController');
```

y estas mis rutas de vue router

```
import ActivityComponent from '../components/ActivityComponent.vue';
import ProductComponent from '../components/ProductComponent.vue';

export const routes = [
    { path: '/home/activity', component: ActivityComponent },
    { path: '/home/product', component: ProductComponent }
];
```

Alguna recomendacion?